# Why the function name start with * in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, function

I am learning Objective C, there is a function:

```
NSArray *desktops = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

When I press command and click function NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains, I see something looks like:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSArray<NSString *> *NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory directory, NSSearchPathDomainMask domainMask, BOOL expandTilde);
```

I don't understand why there is a * before the function name while when I use the function in main.m I don't put * in function name?

Comment: Function doesn't start with `*`, the `*` actually belongs to that `NSArray *`.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! thanks man!!

Comment: The reason why we don't usually write `NSArray*` (without space) is the fact that when declaring multiple variables on the same line `NSArray *array1, *array2` then every variable needs its own asterisk so the asterisk actually belongs to that variable.

Comment: @Sulthan this is a common reason why many C coding guidelines strongly advise against multiple variable declarations on the same line, it is easy to get it wrong.

Comment: @hellofunk I think there are more reasons for that even in other languages :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's pick a slightly simpler signature that will hopefully be clearer:

```
NSArray *GetArray()
```

You can move the space and write this way:

```
NSArray* GetArray()
```

This is a function that returns a pointer to an array. The "*" is part of the type, not part of the name.

It might also be clearer if you think of it this way:

```
(NSArray *) GetArray()
```

or

```
NSArray * GetArray()
```

It's generally a matter of style which you choose. In one case you're emphasizing that the return type is an array, and this function returns a pointer to it. In another, you're emphasizing that the return type is a pointer to an array.

Comment: Thanks, why in the header file - (NSArray *)GetArray; but cannot be - NSArray * GetArray?

Comment: That syntax is for Objective-C methods. The syntax is slightly different than for C functions (like your original example).

Comment: so the function in my example is actually a C function, not a objective - C function.

Comment: Correct. `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` is C. (Remember that Objective-C is a superset of C, so all legal C code is also legal Objective-C code.)

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk is between the type and the function name, that is what matters. It is a matter of style whether you physically attach the pointer to the name of the function, or attach it left, with the name of the return type. The asterisk is not actually part of the function name.

For example, lots of code will show something like `NSArray* some_name` and others will instead write `NSArray *some_name` but they mean the same thing.

In my experience, it seems the vast majority of code I see attaches the pointer to the type, not the variable/function name. But there is no "right" way. I personally have always preferred to attach it to the type to make it clear the return is a pointer.

In this case, it would be a little more odd-looking however, since you'd have:

`NSArray<NSString *>*`

as the return, and that double asterisk does look a bit cryptic at first. Maybe that's why they moved it in this particular case.